# Laravel 5.x - How could Eloquent model be QueryBuilder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to understand how could an Eloquent model also be a query builder. I could not see any polymorphic relationship between `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class and `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class in the source code. There is no inheritance or interface implementation between these two classes.

So, could anyone please explain how Laravel made it possible for an eloquent model to be a query builder? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am asking this question because I don't understand how I could call the methods in `Builder` class through my models, e.g. `ModelObject::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get()`, where orderBy() is a method in `Builder` class.

Comment: Please post the code which is causing the problem. It is possible that you haven't called the get method to retrieve the results?

Comment: @TPHughes, Hi, actually there is no problem. The code is running fine. I just want to understand how I could call the methods in `Builder` class through my models. Please see my editted question. Thank you.

Comment: `Model::newQuery()` creates a query builder instance which ends up creating collections or instances of `Model`. That method is also what is being called in the background when you do things like `Model::where` or other query builder methods on the model

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you. Now I know better about the `Model` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `query()` function on the Eloquent base model which creates a new query builder instance when being called (with the table of the model being already set for the builder). You can find the function [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L828).

Additionally to that, the magic `__call()` and `__callStatic()` functions create a new query builder and delegate the method call to this builder whenever a function is called that is not part of the Eloquent model and which they don't have an implicit call for (like `increment()`, `decrement()`). You can find the code for this [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1498).

So to sum it up: it's magic. The magic functions.

Comment: So whenever a method that is not part of the `Model` class is called, either `__call()` or `__callStatic()`  will automatically be called and those two methods will create a new query builder and call that method through the newly created query builder. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but the actual model is considered, not only the methods of the base model. So custom methods on your models like relations will also still work and not trigger a magic function call. Btw, Laravel uses these magic functions in other places as well.

Comment: I got the idea better now but I still need to learn more about these magic functions. Thank you very much Namoshek for your time.